# You can run nodejs with Johnny-Five in the background on a Debian server?

Tags: node.js, arduino, debian, raspbian, johnny-five

I'm doing a project with nodejs and Johonny-Five, using as a basis a Raspberry PI3 and Arduino Mega as peripheral, but now I need to run the service nodejs with Johnny-Five in the background, which apparently is not possible because it runs for a few seconds and then the service stops. the judgment with which nodejs run the server is "node server.js &" and as I created a systemd service for the execution of server.js to start raspberry but this does not work because constantly restarts, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your function and use it in your server file.

```
function init(){
  board.on("ready", () => {
    var relay = new five.Relay(13);
    board.loop(state.system.tick, function() {
      loop(relay);
    });
  });
}
exports.init = init;
```

in your server.js

```
var PumpController = require('./PumpController.js');

PumpController.init((relay) =>{});
```

checkout my project

https://github.com/kdichev/Green-Systems/blob/development/server.js